# render_template in Python-Flask is not working

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am actually creating an app with Flask and I am encountering issues regarding my routing.

My situation is simple: The user enters a token to authenticate himself. Once he clicks on *authenticate*, an angular HTTP request uses POST to send his token to a Python server. There, if he is granted access, the home page is displayed using `render_template`; otherwise the login keeps still.

However, when the user authenticates himself, I see on my command line that the POST was successful, the authentication was a success but the page just stuck on *login* and does not redirect to *home page* as if the second `render_template` does not work. Please Help!

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('auth.html')  # this is ok.
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')  # this does not work


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    tok = request.form['token']

    if (check_token(tok) == "pass"):  # check_token is a function I've implemented
                                      # to check if token is ok=pass, ko=fail
        session['logged_in'] = True
    else:
        flash("wrong token")

    return index()
```

Comment: However, if i manually set the url on my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` after i have successfully authenticated, that does give me the 'index.html' page...Any idea?

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245814/flask-redirect-with-authentication. You would need redirect upon successful authentication. You may want to try `Flash-Login` library from https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Answer (score 5):

Your `login` handler shouldn't call `index` directly. It should return a [redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.redirect) to the index.

```
return redirect('/')
```

or better:

```
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: I tried both but same issue..
 `@app.route('/')
def index():
 if not session.get('logged_in'):
  return render_template('auth.html')
  
 else:
  return render_template('index.html')



@app.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
 tok=request.form['token']
 
 if (check_token(tok)=="pass"):
  session['logged_in'] = True;
 else:
  flash("wrong token")
 
 return redirect(url_for('index')) 
`

Comment: However, if i manually set the url on my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` after i have successfully authenticated, that does give me the 'index.html' page...Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of the following.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')  

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if request.method = "POST":
        tok = request.form['token']

        if (check_token(tok) == "pass"):  
            session['logged_in'] = True
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

        else:
            flash("wrong token")

    return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: Thanks but still nothing. I see my GET request for a page changing on the CLI but nothing on browser...

Comment: There might be an indentation error in my example. The return redirect url for index should move up 4 spaces. Not sure though is that solves your issue. Please add the app log if running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Angular JS in my app to send requests to my flask server and i realised that my client side angular JS had difficulties in rendering page as it was just expecting a response. 
I first tried to do.. `document.write('response.data')` and it did display my home page but my scripts attached on my html page stopped working.
Second try, I tried to reload the page after receiving the response in my client and it works well. I don't know if it's the best way to do but it does work.